# Как правильно компилировать с помощью cmd.exe?

Tags: java

Задам нубский вопрос: как компилировать через cmd.exe в моем случае программу? В файле MiniDuckSimulator нах-ся psvm. Где я вообще могу посмотреть, как правильно компилировать файлы в различных случаях, а то я не очень понимаю, когда использовать -cp, -sourcepath, -classpath и т.п. Мне очень хотелось бы разобраться вэтом вопросе и научиться архивировать, распаковывать через командную строку. Что можете посоветовать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На habr имеется неплохая [статья](https://habr.com/ru/post/125210/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Консольная утилита [`javac`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/javac.html#GUID-AEEC9F07-CB49-4E96-8BC7-BCC2C7F725C9):**

Используется для компиляции программы, основной опцией которой является:

- `--source-path` / `-sourcepath` - указывает на каталог, в котором находятся файлы исходного кода (для java - это файлы с расширением `.java`):

  - используется при компиляции исходников в байткод (в `.class` файлы);

**Консольная утилита [`java`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html#GUID-3B1CE181-CD30-4178-9602-230B800D4FAE):**

Используется для запуска программы, основной опцией которой является:

- `--class-path path` / `-classpath path` / `-cp` - указывает на каталог, в котором находятся скомпилированные файлы (`.class`):

  - используется при запуске программы (за счет интерпретации на стороне JVM файлов байткода, т.е. `.class` файлов).

**Консольная утилита [`jar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jar.html#GUID-51C11B76-D9F6-4BC2-A805-3C847E857867):**

Используется для манипуляции с архивами (создания архивов, извлечение из них `.class` файлов, ...), основной опцией которой является:

- `--create` / `-c` - создание архива.

**На изучение:**

1. [статья](https://habr.com/ru/post/125210/) на habr, посвященная вашему вопросу;
2. [официальная документация на консольную утилиту javac](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/javac.html#GUID-AEEC9F07-CB49-4E96-8BC7-BCC2C7F725C9) (в рамках JDK 11);
3. [официальная документация на консольную утилиту java](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html#GUID-3B1CE181-CD30-4178-9602-230B800D4FAE) (в рамках JDK 11);
4. [официальная документация на консольную утилиту jar](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jar.html#GUID-51C11B76-D9F6-4BC2-A805-3C847E857867) (в рамках JDK 11).